# Merge 10 variables in pairs and make them into one variable

Tags: r, variables

This is how my files looks like :

```
#Var1    Var2   Var3  Var4
#0         1    2       1
```

I want something like this :

```
#Var1     Var2
#01        21
```

I am sorry for any inconvenience, I tried to be as clear as possible in asking this question. I am very new to R and stackoverflow. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Try `with(mydf,paste0(Var1,Var2))` or `with(mydf,Var1*10+Var2)`.

Comment: Are they vectors or data.frames?

Comment: @Shreyos: Thanks for formatting. I did not know how to do that.

Comment: @arun: They are dataframes.

Comment: @Venkatesh, since you are new to SO, I suggest you read [this *about* page](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: How big is your actual data.frame? (how many columns and rows, use `dim(your_data_frame)`)\

Comment: @arun: I have 43 rows and 16627 columns.

Comment: @arun: Thanks for the link. I will read through the page and keep my questions to the point

Comment: Okay in that case, you'll have to know about `lapply/sapply`. good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way (assuming `tt` is your `data.frame`):

```
sapply(seq(1, ncol(tt), by=2), function(x) do.call(paste0, c(tt[,x:(x+1)])))
# [1] "01" "21"
```

(or) as @Sven shows under comment:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1, ncol(tt), by=2), 
         function(x) do.call(paste0, c(tt[,x:(x+1)])))), names(tt)[1:2])
```

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, thanks. when I wrap this `sapply` with `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()`, I get my command as column name.. Any idea why this happens and how to get a  data.frame directly with proper column names?

Comment: My proposal: Change `sapply` to `lapply` and use `setNames`. The complete command: `setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1, ncol(tt), by=2), function(x) do.call(paste0, c(tt[,x:(x+1)])))), names(tt)[1:2])`

Comment: awesome! I'll remember that.

Comment: @arun:   sapply(seq(1, ncol(sub), by=2), function(x) do.call(paste0, c(sub[,x:(x+1)])))  Error in `[.data.frame`(sub, , x:(x + 1)) : undefined columns selected <code> .  I keep getting this error. I am not sure where I specified wrong column size. Thanks

Comment: I think your data.frame has odd number of columns... what does `ncol(sub)` give you?

Comment: Yes in that case, how do you want to paste? you would have merged 1 and 2, 3 and 4, ... , 16625 and 16626... And you have 1 hanging column.. With what do you want this to be pasted?

Comment: I know the reason. The last variable is a individual variable. I will remove that column and try. Thanks again.

Comment: yes. indeed, you got it right. In that case you'll have to do: `seq(1, ncol(sub)-1, by=2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# The data
dat <- data.frame(0, 1, 2, 1)

# Transform data
as.data.frame(lapply(c(1, 3), function(x) paste(dat[c(x, x+1)], collapse = "")))

  X.01. X.21.
1    01    21
```

Comment: No need to confuse the OP with `lapply` ... Keep it simple.

Comment: @Roland, what's the confusion?

Comment: I believe we should assume the OP doesn't know `*apply` functions.

Comment: @TylerRinker True, but then the answers need more detailed explanations.

Comment: @Tylerrinker:I will look into the help page and try to understand the code in detail. Thanks again for your effort.